# How to capture parts of a string into groups using regex?

Tags: regex

I need to capture 4 groups from:

```
John.7200_24.6.txt.gz
```

Output:

```
Group1: John
Group2: 7200
Group3: 24
Group4: 6
```

Here is my regex: `([^.|_|data|gz]+)`

It captures a single group with multiple matches. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern `([^.|_|data|gz]+)` can be written as `([^._datagz|]+)` which uses a negated character class to match 1+ chars other than the single chars listed.

You use a single capture group to split on, if you want 4 separate groups, you should create 4 groups and match instead of split.

```
^(\w+)\.(\d+)_(\d+)\.(\d+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\w+)\.` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 1** and match `.`
- `(\d+)_` Capture 1+ digits in **group 2** and match `_`
- `(\d+)\.` Capture 1+ digitsin **group 3** and match `.`
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 4**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ghuqI2/1)

Or matching the full example string:

```
^(\w+)\.(\d+)_(\d+)\.(\d+)\.\w+\.gz$
```